# How to cleanly ask user for input and allow several types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style, code-cleanup

So this is a prompt for user input, and it works just fine. I was printing some names and associated (1 based) numbers to the console for the user to choose one. I am also giving the option to quit by entering q.
The condition for the number to be valid is a) it is a number and b) it is smaller or equal than the number of names and greater than 0.

```
while True:    
    number = str(input("Enter number, or q to quit. \n"))
    if number == "q":
        sys.exit()
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except:
        continue
    if number <= len(list_of_names) and number > 0:
        name = list_of_names[number-1]
        break
```

There is no problem with this code, except I find it hard to read, and not very beautiful. Since I am new to python I would like to ask you guys, how would you code this prompt more cleanly? To be more specific: How do I ask the user for input that can be either a string, or an integer?

Comment: Aside from the indenting, looks ok. You could make use of `else` and `finally` or multiple `except`s. Also, `if number in range(..)`. And t think input returns a string already.

Comment: `if number.isdigit() and int(number) in range(len(list_of_names)):`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That doesn't really help because then you have to convert the input to an int _again_ when you index the list, and also the number is 1-based.

Comment: This probably belongs on [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Rawing:  I'm not sure if your objection is based on performance or elegance.  If performance it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think a (significantly) better solution exists. We're stuck getting number inputs from the user through a text interface like some kind of stone age people.

Comment: Maybe you should have a separate variable instead of `number` before you actually know if it's a number or not. `if number == "q":` looks a bit strange. How can a number be equal to the string "q"?

Comment: @gurka:  Good point.  I renamed it `choice` in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit simpler:

```
while True:    
    choice = str(input("Enter number, or q to quit. \n"))
    if choice.lower() == "q":
        sys.exit()
    elif choice.isdigit() and (0 < int(choice) <= len(list_of_names)):
        name = list_of_names[int(choice)-1] 
        break
```

Comment: So this works. You are avoiding the try/except part, i like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just downcase it.

```
number = str(input("Enter number, or q to quit. \n"))
number = number.lower()
```

That will make the q lower case so it doesn't matter if they press it with shift if they press something else just make a if statement that sets a while loop true.